# Php: defaulting optional param performance

Tags: php, performance

In php, is there a difference in performance if the calling function fills in the optional parameters (with their respective defaults), or just leave them blank?

For example:

```
function foo($id, $a = '', $b = false) {
.....
}
```

Which is faster:

```
foo(1234);
```

or

```
foo(1234, '', false);
```

Comment: did you measure it ? please enlighten us !

Comment: have you optimized everything else in your system so much that the **MICROSCOPIC** speed difference between the two  has a huge effect on your app?

Comment: You don't optimize code this way. You need to profile your entire application and then target the slowest parts first.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter as far as speed, but it certainly helps out with readability and code duplication. Setting defaults means, you don't have to set the same values in multiple places in your code stack which means READABILITY AND CONSISTENCY!

Comment: One could also argue that optional arguments abstract away implementation details, leading to code that is less explicit and therefore more difficult to follow (especially the first time you see it).

Comment: I disagree! If you are making a base function that is suppose to be reusable and there happens to be 1 small difference that you have to use every once in a while, it would be better to add the optional arguments rather than copy and paste and have nasty duplication. And you should document your code base. ;)